# What is the field's role in a linear space?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, field-theory

A linear space $(U,F,\oplus,\odot)$ is a set of vectors $U$ and a field $(F,+,\cdot)$ for which vector addition $\oplus:V\times V\to V$ and scalar multiplication $\odot:F\times V\to V$ are defined. These satisfy a bunch of properties, but these are irrelevant to my question.

In my professor's notes, the following is written:

> The vectors $\{(1,0,0),(0,1,0),(0,0,1)\}$ form the canonical basis for the linear space $\mathbb C^3$ over the field $\mathbb C$; therefore $\mathbb C^3$ over $\mathbb C$ has dimension 3. On the other hand, $\mathbb C^3$ is a linear space also over the field $\mathbb R$; in this case it has dimension 6, the following being a basis: $\{(1,0,0),(i,0,0),(0,1,0),(0,i,0),(0,0,1),(0,0,i)\}$.

Please help me to understand this. I am having a difficult time understanding what it means to be a linear space "over the field $\mathbb C$" vs. "over the field $\mathbb R$" and how that leads to the bases that are defined above.

Thanks a lot for your time helping me out!

Comment: The short answer is that the constant multiples change.  If you're allowed to multiply by elements of $\mathbb{C}$, then $(1,0,0)$ and $(i,0,0)$ are just scalar multiples of each other.  If you are only allowed to multiply by elements of $\mathbb{R}$, then $(1,0,0)$ and $(i,0,0)$ are *not* multiples of each other because there is no real factor that changes one into the other.

Comment: usually nobody uses $\oplus$ and $\odot$ for the operations

Comment: @MichaelBurr sorry, that did not help to clear it up. If you could post a longer answer that explains it a little more...

Answer (score 1):

Just take the simpler example of the field $\mathbf C$  itself: it can be considered a vector space over itself, and $1$ is a basis, since for any complex number $z$, we can write $z=z\times 1$ in a unique way.

But  $\mathbf C$  can also be considered a vector space over $\mathbf R$. In this case it is no more of dimension $1$: you make take any complex number $u$, you won't obtain another complex number  $z$ as $z=\lambda u$, $\;\lambda \in\mathbf R$ since in general, the quotient $\dfrac zu$ is *not* real.

Instead, you can write $z=x+\mathrm iy=x\cdot 1+y\cdot\mathrm i$  $(x,y\in\mathbf R)$. This shows  $\mathbf C$ has a basis of $2$ elements as a real vector-space,  i.e. $\;\dim_{\mathbf R} \mathbf C=2$.

More generally, any finite-dimensional complex vector-space $E$ is also (by restriction of scalars) a finite-dimensional real vector-space, and:
$$\dim_{\mathbf R}E=2\dim_{\mathbf C}E. $$

Answer (score 0):

To specify a triple in ${\Bbb C}^3$ you need three complex numbers.

But to specify an element in the space generated by 
$$(1,0,0),(0,i,0),(0,1,0),(0,i,0),(0,0,1),(0,0,i),$$
you need six scalars in $\Bbb R$.

Each expression
$$a(1,0,0)+b(0,i,0)+c(0,1,0)+d(0,i,0)+e(0,0,1)+f(0,0,i),$$
can be identified with a combination of triples
$$(a+bi)(1,0,0)+(c+di)(0,1,0)+(e+fi)(0,0,1),$$
which is just $(a+bi,c+di,e+fi)$.